# get form values from one php "echo" to the other

Tags: php, html

i want get the values of form in other php file but i am getting only one input value as the name are same in loop....How to get all the input values with the same name or if i have to change the name tell me how? and how to get it in other php file

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    //getting values of number of MCQ questions and true/false questions
    $mcq = $_POST['mcq'];
    $truefalse = $_POST['truefalse'];
    $number = 1;

    echo '<form action="finalquestions.php" method="post">';

    //loop to get inputs of mcq as many as the user posted
    for($i=1;$i<=$mcq;$i++){
        echo 'Question:'.$number.'<input type="text" name="question1" /> </br></br>';
        echo '<input type="radio" name="radio1"> <input type="text" name="radiooptions" /> </br>
              <input type="radio" name="radio1"> <input type="text" name="radiooptions" /> </br>
              <input type="radio" name="radio1"> <input type="text" name="radiooptions" /> </br>
              <input type="radio" name="radio1"> <input type="text" name="radiooptions" /> </br>';
        echo '</br></br>';
        $number++;
    }

    //loop to get inputs of truefalse as many as the user posted        
    for($i=1;$i<=$truefalse;$i++){
        echo 'Question:'.$number.' <input type="text" name="question2" /> </br></br>';
        echo '<input type="radio" name="question2">True</br>
              <input type="radio" name="question1">False</br>';
        echo '</br></br>';
        $number++;
    }
}

?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>WebQuiz Generator</title>
</head>
<body>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate Quiz" />

</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Give `name="radioX"` different numbers or create an array

Comment: Your HTML is invalid - no opening <form> tag.

Comment: @DaveP `<form>` is present, although, I don't see the closing tag `</form>`

Comment: change to radio[], then it'll come in as an array.  Or assign it name of radio".$i."  so it's radio1,radio2,radio3

Comment: @PedroLobito Scroll down to the bottom.

Comment: @DaveP I see, but all the `php` content is being generate outside the `<html>`, scary...

Comment: @PedroLobito I missed the opening tag, you missed the closing one. I suspect the PHP interpreter will do even less well that either of us.